# Install selenium library in vscode on macos for python

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I followed youtube video on how to unfold virtual environment and install selenium in vscode on macos
and went through some commands:

pip install pipenv

pipenv shell

pipenv install selenium

After that I got success message but Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock showed 0/0..

Even though content of Pipfile is:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
selenium = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

When I tried to write my first script:
from selenium import
I realized that IDE doesn't see selenium!

Unfortunately I have very limited experience in macOS admin. Please help me to discover what went wrong
and why it cannot see selenium!

Comment: Did you follow the VSCode documentation for using virtual environments (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) ?

Comment: I went through this doc but it's very hard for me to understand it.. As far as I understand my pipenv is active and python interpreter is alright is just that it doesn't see selenium

Comment: What does your `Pipfile.lock` file show?

Comment: I managed to resolve this after closing and opening VSCode. Selenium became visible